# typescript dependency injection with little footprint

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

I am new to nodejs and typescript, coming from C#.
I want to use dependency injection in my project and found that the most popular package is inversify.

I started using it but I don't like the fact that I have to add decorators all over.

for example it bothers me that I need to add @inject before parameters in the constructor:

```
public constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.Weapon) katana: Weapon,
    @inject(TYPES.ThrowableWeapon) shuriken: ThrowableWeapon
)
```

This mean every class has to know the TYPES object...

I don't understand why @inject needs the string literal and can't inject just on the basis of the type...

Is there a neater way to do this?

Comment: "just on the basis of the type" --- I'm not familiar with that library, but TS itself does not exist in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contrast to strictly typed languages, TypeScript types don't exist at runtime. It's possible to use type information at runtime for dependency injection but in limited ways. With the use of `emitDecoratorMetadata` TypeScript option it's possible to get constructor parameter types and use them for DI.

The example is [`injection-js`](https://github.com/mgechev/injection-js), which is Angular injector that was extracted from the library for standalone use. Only `@Injectable` decorator is needed to be used on DI-enabled class, `@Inject` parameter decorators are optional.

The limitations are that only class instances can be injected this way:

```
constructor(foo: FooClass) {}
```

Generics are ignored and discarded:

```
constructor(foo: FooClass<Bar>) {}
```

Other types are ignored and result in DI error:

```
constructor(foo: fooSymbol) {}

constructor(foo: 'foo string provider') {}
```

The same [applies to InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/constructor_injection.md):

> In case of concrete injections, you can simply define your constructor
>   parameters as usual without using the @inject decorator.
>
> InversifyJS also supports TypeScript's constructor assignments so you
>   can have private or protected access modifiers in your parameters and
>   the container will have no trouble injecting the dependencies

It would be possible to omit `@inject` for `Weapon` and `ThrowableWeapon` if they were classes but in listed example [`TYPES.Weapon` is a symbol and `Weapon` is an interface that doesn't exist at runtime](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/README.md#step-1-declare-your-interfaces-and-types), so `@inject` is necessary.

Comment: I understand... so I have to use the decorators if I want to use interfaces.

Comment: Yes. Or you can stick to classes because they allow you to omit @inject. In TS classes act as interfaces but also exist at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean "n TS classes act as interfaces but also exist at runtime." ?

Comment: It's possible to use `class Foo {}` as a type (interface) like `let foo: Foo` but it stays a class (a function) that can be used at runtime, `foo = new Foo`. That's the quality that is used by DI libs that are listed in the answer. You couldn't do that if `Foo` were `interface Foo {}`. That's how TS differs from C#.